# How can I allow the user to download spreadsheets created using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xlsx

In my controller I have some code to create add content to my workbook

```
def report

   p = Axlsx::Package.new
   wb = p.workbook
   wb.add_wordsheet(:name => "Viewer Summary") do |sheet|
       sheed.add_row["LOL"]
   end

 end
```

My sheet has a lot more stuff added to the sheet but I do not think it is necessary to type it all out.

In my view I have a button that calls the above report method in the controller.  When the user clicks the button I want the users browser to Download the spreadsheet.  Is this possible with the axlsx gem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are looking for is `send_data` http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data

basically you would do this, although I'd consider removing the creation and adding data to wb to its own class.

```
def report

  p = Axlsx::Package.new
  wb = p.workbook
  wb.add_wordsheet(:name => "Viewer Summary") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row["LOL"]
  format.xlsx { send_data(wb) } #something similar to that.
  end

end
```